# Google analytics api - Get data with time interval

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I have a requirement to fetch google analytics events data using analyics api with some interval. Lets say 5min is the interval then I want to get event count fired every 5 mins with hour and date. Is it possible to create a query for this?

I managed to get every minute data using query dimensions **ga:day,ga:minute,ga:hour** it gives me data for every minute, but it will be great if I can get data with 5min interval.

I am using ruby client to get the data. I made a query like this

```
result = client.execute(:api_method => api_method, :parameters => {
  'ids'        => profile,
  'start-date' => (params[:from_date]).to_s,
  'end-date'   => (params[:to_date]).to_s,
  'dimensions' => 'ga:day,ga:minute,ga:hour,ga:eventAction,ga:eventCategory',
  'metrics'    => 'ga:uniqueEvents',
  'filters'    => 'ga:eventCategory==Sign up event'
  })
```

It gives me results of every minute data. Just wanted to know whether it is possible to group this data in minutes.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried.

Comment: Have you tried using [histogram buckets](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/basics#histogram_buckets)

Comment: @ItamarGreen I have edited the question and mentioned what I have tried